# Android 12 - About Correspondence to notification trampoline

Tags: android

We are working on notification trampolines on Android 12.
Originally our app launches an activity by a broadcast receiver.

I found out that using `PendingIntent.getActivity` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` would solve the problem.

Regarding this, I have a following concern.
When the broadcast receiver is used, i.e. when `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` is used,   I programmed so that the broadcast receiver determines whether to launch the app.
However, I no longer use the broadcast receiver due to notification trampolines. Therefore, `PendingIntent.getActivity` launches the app without choice.
I would like to know if there is any way to determine whether to launch the app depending of the state of app without using the broadcast receiver.

For example;

- when App is in state A:Launch the app with a push notification tap
- when App is in state B:NOT launch the app with a push notification tap

Answer (score 0):

sort of workaround would be to launch some dedicated `Activity`, which may be set as [fully transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android) without any enter/exit animation, `noHistory` flag etc. and in there you may run your checking logic - starting "real" `Activity` or just `finish()` if there is no need

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a transparent activity to handle this issue. all the notification related works are handled in the transparent activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("notification", parseInt(this.mActionDetail.getNotifyId()));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
notificationManager.notify(parseInt(this.mActionDetail.getNotifyId()), builder.build());
```

create a transparent activity NotificationActivity.class then you can identify the application state then you can decide the action